# ExtJs form multiple button for different binding

Tags: javascript, extjs

Need to bind my form elements separately for different buttons. Using allowBlank in elements for sending binding conditions and formBind in buttons for binding the buttons. Need to do this like in this simplest way. (ExtJs 4.2.1 Classic)

**Example**

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
 ......
 items: [
  Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Date', {
   .....,
   allowBlank: false, //bind for both search & download button.
   .....
  }),
  ......, //// All rest elements bind for both search & download button.
  Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
   ......,
   allowBlank: false, //bind for only download button.
   ......
  })
 ],
 buttons: [
  {
   text: 'Search',
   formBind: true,  /// Need to bind for specific field only.
  },
  {
   text: 'Download',
   formBind: true,  /// Need to bind for all.
  },
  ............
});
```

If any other data or details is necessary then please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: Write a change handler for the specific field and control the disabled state manually.

Comment: Can you give any example or details as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard quick way to do this, you might want to write a plugin for this. I've put together one:

```
Ext.define('App.plugin.MultiDisableBind', {
    extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
    alias: 'plugin.multidisablebind',

    /**
     * @cfg
     * Reference to the fields that this button depends on.
     * Can contain either direct references, or a query selectors that will be
     * executed with the button as the root
     */
    depFields: null,

    /**
     * @property
     * A map object with field ids as key, and field values as value
     */
    valuesMap: null,

    init: function (cmp) {
        this.setCmp(cmp);

        cmp.on('render', this.setup, this);
    },

    setup: function () {
        var cmp = this.getCmp(),
            depFields = this.depFields,
            valuesMap = {};

        if (!Ext.isArray(depFields)) {
            depFields = [depFields];
        }

        Ext.Array.forEach(depFields, function (field) {
            if (Ext.isString(field)) {
                field = cmp.query(field)[0];
            }

            cmp.mon(
                field,
                'change',
                Ext.Function.createThrottled(this.updateValuesMap, 300, this),
                this
            );
            valuesMap[field.getId()] = field.getValue();
        }, this);

        this.valuesMap = valuesMap;
        this.updateCmpDisabled();
    },

    updateValuesMap: function (depField, newValue) {
        this.valuesMap[depField.getId()] = newValue;
        this.updateCmpDisabled();
    },

    updateCmpDisabled: function () {
        var cmp = this.getCmp(),
            toDisable = true;

        Ext.Object.each(this.valuesMap, function (fieldId, fieldValue) {
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(fieldValue)) {
                toDisable = false;
                return false
            }
        });

        cmp.setDisabled(toDisable);
    }
});
```

You can use this plugin in your buttons like so:

```
xtype: 'button',
text: 'My button',
plugins: {
    ptype: 'multidisablebind',
    depFields: ['^form #fieldQuery', fieldVar]
}
```

In the `depFields` config you specify references to the fields that button's disabled state depends on, and the plugin will monitor these fields, so that on each field value change it will update the disabled state.

Here is a working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28cm

Comment: Thanks. That's all I'm searching for.

Comment: I still don't understand how you think a custom plugin is "simplest way" when a few lines out of the box achieves the same thing.

Comment: @TommyO imagine that he has a dozen of fields.. By setting change listeners to every field he might end up with more repetitive lines of code that are harder to maintain. I also think that is more appropriate to specify this binding behavior on the buttons than on the fields. Fields should not care about the buttons, buttons are interested in the fields. The plugin solution is also more appropriate when the buttons are getting deleted. Everything gets cleaned up, in your solution you would need to also check if the button is available in order to anticipate this.

Comment: @scebotari66 Don't get me wrong, I think this very good solution. It's just OP never stated that buttons are going to be deleted in his app therefore I didn't write code that would anticipate that. Nor did OP state that he was going to be using the solution on a dozen fields.  I just gave an easy-to-implement solution for a question that explicitly asked to keep it simple.

Comment: @TommyO Fair point. I just always try to anticipate common scenarios and write reusable code

Answer (score 3):

I created a fiddle here that I think should accomplish what you're trying to do. The idea to use an event listener on the combobox, instead of the `formBind` config of the `Download` button:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/289a

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    itemId: 'exampleForm',
    items: [Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Date', {
            allowBlank: false, //bind for both search & download button.
        }),
        Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            allowBlank: false, //bind for only download button.
            listeners: {
                change: function (thisCombo, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                    if (Ext.isEmpty(newValue)) {
                        thisCombo.up('#exampleForm').down('#btnDownload').setDisabled(true);
                    } else {
                        thisCombo.up('#exampleForm').down('#btnDownload').setDisabled(false);
                    }
                }
            },
            store: ['item1', 'item2']
        })
    ],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Search',
        formBind: true, /// Need to bind for specific field only.
    }, {
        itemId: 'btnDownload',
        text: 'Download',
        disabled: true
            //formBind: true, /// Need to bind for all.
    }]
});
```

Comment: I understand, but I don't know of a more efficient way to do it in v4.2 seeing as there's no way to specify what you're trying to do within the config. I see @Evan Trimboli also recommended this approach to you and I'm pretty sure he's a developer for Sencha ExtJs. Anyway, hope you find your answer!

Comment: @MAKRipon it absolutely works exactly how you specified. - I just double checked it. I didn't attach a store to the combobox because I figured you could just type into the combo for the sake of the example. But please be more specific when you say "it is not working", so I can address the issue if there is one. Thanks.

Comment: Both buttons are getting binded for both items. It should have binded differently. Like search button only for date.

Comment: The download button is not binded to the form.  There is an event listener on the `ComboBox` that determines whether or not the download button is disabled. Have you looked at the code above?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/283g) for you. The code uses `bind` and `formBind` respectively for the two different buttons. May be you want something like this.

Comment: Try with the version indicated.

Comment: Sorry..I did not see the version